# Add game tag to answered game identification question?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-identification

Once a game identification question is answered, and the asker acknowledges the answer, would it make sense to add the tag for the game to the question?

I think this would primarily serve to alert people following that tag, who could then take a look and vote or comment.

The drawback that occurs to me would be if someone wanted to post a competing answer for another game, but if the first answer is already acknowledged as correct then that wouldn't be much of a drawback.

Just something that occurred to me after looking at an answered question, and feeling like it was a bit odd to see a screenshot of a game, but no tag for that game on the question.